# Answer in Buttons Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am new to swift and working on a new project.

I have two labels that has random Integer values inside and I make an addition and display the answer in a button. I couldn't figure out how to have four options(buttons) where the correct answer changes randomly among these options.

I might be doing this in a wrong way as I said I am new, please suggest me a way to solve this issue.

```
@IBOutlet var number1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var number2: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet var result: UILabel!   
@IBOutlet var option1: UIButton!

var randomNumber1:Int = 0
var randomNumber2:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {       
    super.viewDidLoad()

    randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    option1.setTitle("\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

@IBAction func option1Pressed(sender: UIButton){

    randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    option1.setTitle("\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly match to requirement.

Addition numbers are random !!, Its answer is random !! and also all four options are placed at random!!.

**Check List:**

1. Addition numbers are within specific range, you can change it in code.
2. There are four options (answer) which are random placed.
3. Only one correct answer, Also each number distinct with each other.
4. Answers lies in range - between low end (lowest from two number) and answer (total of both number)

Here's a sample code. I have placed some critical conditions too, for possible breaks.

### [Click here to download below sample...](http://jmp.sh/5I0MYW8)

[image]

Comment: @user3499983: A simple demo for you. Match with your requirement, have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Demo is also very helpful. Is it important to add "as Int"?

Comment: In Swift unwrapping variable is important otherwise when you assign values it will gives you compile time error sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
number1.integerValue = randomNumber1
```

the "(randomNumber1)" syntax is something you would use in a println statement.